# remove index.php from zend framework url

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, indexing

I am developing a module using zend framework and I have created a project using zf create project
command

when i try to access the url using `ip/folder/controller/action` it is giving error not found error when i try access using `ip/folder/index.php/controller/action` i am able to access but i am unable to include js,css files  in both cases and my htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

and the index.php is

```
<?php

   // Define path to application directory
   defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
   || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/application'));

   // Define application environment
    defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') 
       ? getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') : 'production'));

   // Ensure library/ is on include_path
     set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, 
     array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/library'), get_include_path(),
)));

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';    

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
);
$application->bootstrap()->run();
```

Comment: you need to enable mode rewrite.

Comment: mod_rewrite is already enabled

Comment: then your web server doesn't see .htaccess file. Do you have Linux/Apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this to your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9} /([^/]+/)*index.php 
RewriteRule ^index.php(.*)$ /path/to/your/installation$1 [R=301,L]
```

Replace /path/to/your/installation with the correct path

Comment: can you tell me how to configure the path to installation with example

Comment: you can also do this:

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

Comment: In any case it should point to the location where your index.php is located. The latter example however, should cover your use case as well.

Answer (score 0):

I just add this to the top of the index.php:

```
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = str_replace('index.php', '', $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

which is the other method suggested by [Rob Allen at Akrabat.com](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/remove-index-php-from-your-url/)