# Zend Framework URL problems

Tags: php, url, zend-framework

URL *http:// l o c a l h o s t/HelloZend/public/**index.php**/artist/* works properly, but i don't like to see **index.php** there placed.
If URL is *http:// l o c a l h o s t/HelloZend/public/artist/* then the message is

> Not Found - The requested URL /HelloZend/public/artist/ was not found
>   on this server.

What's the problem? I've already tried to configure Apache, but in that type of URL it always try to open folder */ a r t i s  t /* instead of calling controller ***a r t i s t*** or whatever is in URL. Same situation is with controller/action and so on.

Comment: possible duplicate of [remove index.php from zend framework url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353252/remove-index-php-from-zend-framework-url)

Comment: Please post your Apache config file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add .htaccess file to your public folder

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```